# Set up htaccess redirect to an identically titled directory on a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

If example.com is my primary domain, how can i get http://example.com/holiday to 301 redirect to http://referrals.example.com/holiday ? I've tried the following but am getting a redirect loop error message when trying to visit the page:

```
RewriteRule ^holiday$ http://referrals.example.com/holiday/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` before this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(holiday/?)$ http://referrals.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```